# Get item if in list and its position in the list, & a little guidance in ExcelWriter

Tags: pandas, for-loop, python-3.6, pandas.excelwriter

I hope this is not duplicate.

This is a problem that I have in a script where I am using pandas and ExcelWriter to create an excel for data visualization.

What I am trying to do is style the column width and cell format of my columns, according to the total width of the original title of each column (so not all columns have the same width). And, as an additional problem, not all the columns have the same cell format. Imagine I have 3 format_types.

This is how I am approaching the problem, but I hope there is a better way.

For format_type_1:

From all the columns, I get a sublist of the columns that need to have that format_type_1. But they are not in order, maybe the columns are col0, col4 and col10. So I need to know the position of the columns in the list of all the columns.

Then, I plan on using them iterating a zip of both lists (item,position), in order to set the width and the cell format. Like this:

```
widths = [len(x) for x in sublist]
for i, width in (zip(i, widths)):
    worksheet.set_column(i, i, width*0.9, cell_format)
```

So, going back a little bit, I have my full list of columns:

```
list = [ 'Item1','Item2','Item3', ... ,'Itemn' ]
```

And this is how I get the sublist of columns

```
sublist = [elem for elem in list if elem in ('Item1', 'Item4')]
```

But now, I don't know how to get the list with the positions of those elements in the original list. I could define them, saying, position is 0 and 3, but I would rather not. If the position is not correct, then set_column will apply the style to the first ones.

Is there a better way of doing this? Because if this is the way, I would have to do all this thing 3 times, one for each of my format styles, taking only the columns that I need to format. I feel it's too much.

Let me know if I need to further clarify. Thanks.